# Me ayudan con este bug

Tags: php

Me ayudan con este Bug que tengo por favor . 
Estoy tratando de eliminar ese STRING que sale en la parte superior izquierda de la página.
Cuando escribo una entrada invalida me sale ese el la cantidad de string mas el texto de dicha entrada.

Como ven en la imagen estoy tratando de escribir la palabra hola en una entrada y me sale el mismo string mas la cantidad de dicho estring en la parte superior izquierda de la página web.
[image: como ven en la imagen estoy tratando de escribir la palabra hola en una entrada y me sale ese ese el mismo string mas la cantidad de dicho estring en la parte superior izquierda de la página web.]

```
public function mostrar_texto() {
        if ($this -> texto != "" && strlen(trim($this -> texto)) > 0) {
            echo $this -> texto;
        }
    }
```

Comment: public function mostrar_texto() {
        if ($this -> texto != "" && strlen(trim($this -> texto)) > 0) {
            echo $this -> texto;
        }
    }

Comment: Es mejor si editas tu pregunta y añades el código solicitado.

Comment: creo que eso es un var_dump...

Comment: intenta colocar todo el código de la sección que compete, no solo una función.

Comment: Exacto, ¿qué contiene la propiedad `$this->texto`?

Comment: Como te han dicho, eso es un var_dump. Busca esa cadena en tu proyecto, seguro que en alguna parte tienes uno y te está mostrando ese resultado.

Comment: Es efectos habia sido el var_dump. Muchas gracias

Comment: Gracias. Habia sido el var_dump. Muchas Gracias.